# Android Calendar illegalArgumentException when calendar.month set to 1

Tags: android, android-calendar

The code below works fine except when `calendar.MONTH set to 1 (Feb)`,and  I do not know why ?
Thanks.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setLenient(false);    
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);    
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1); // Only when "Feb" failed with illegalArgumentException    

    int maxDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); <= If Calendar.MONTH set to 1, this line will "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the current date in getInstance.  Then you're setting the month to February.  The problem is that today is the 30th.  February has 28 days.  That's an illegal combo.  Change the day to a valid day, then change the month.

Comment: @andrewwang1TW If that solve your problem.. Don't forgot to mark it as answer by clicking on the right mark beside the answer..

Comment: @Pragnani, lots of marker on StackOverflow, I have checked several markers, but not sure which one is the "mark it as answer"... "right marker beside the answer" ?

Answer (score -1):

Change field names in set method

```
calendar.YEAR   to   Calender.YEAR
calendar.MONTH   to  Calender.MONTH
```

They are static fields and should be referrred with the Class

Comment: Thanks. it's typo, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" remains, even Calender.YEAR and Calender.Month.