# Calendar.getTime IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception, week-number, java.util.calendar, java-calendar

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class WeekYear {
    static String input = "202001";
    //static String format = "YYYYMM";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Calendar lCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(lCal.isLenient());
        lCal.setLenient(false);
        lCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, new Integer(input.substring(0, 4)).intValue());
        lCal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, new Integer(input.substring(4, 6)).intValue());
        //lCal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(5);
        System.out.println(lCal.isLenient());
        System.out.println(lCal.getTime());

        //lCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, new Integer(input.substring(0, 4)).intValue());
        //lCal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, new Integer(input.substring(4, 6)).intValue());
        //System.out.println(lCal.getTime());
    }
}
```

When this code is executed on Nov 22nd, 2020 I get an IllegalArgumentException from Calendar.getTime(). But when executed on Nov 27, 2020 it works fine.

The documentation says:

> The `setLenient(boolean leniency)` method in `Calendar` class is used to specify whether the interpretation of the date and time is to be lenient or not. Parameters: The method takes one parameter `leniency` of the `boolean` type that refers to the mode of the calendar.

Any explanation? I am not able to reproduce the issue even in my local now. Local time is set to CST

Exception Stack:

``````````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: year: 2020 -> 2019
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2829)
at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1755)
at WildDog.main(WildDog.java:13)
`````````
``````````

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214838/illegalargumentexception-on-calendar-gettime-when-lenient-is-false), @Gopinathan? If not, you should mention it in your post.

Comment: Are you running your code on a computer the clock of which is about one year ahead? And does the exception come from `lCal.setLenient(false);` according to the stack trace?

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I set my computer’s time to Nov 22, 2020, and ran your code. No exception was seen (output included `Sun Jan 05 13:54:27 CST 2020`).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @Ole probably because you/we are in Europe and have different definition of first day of week (and minimum days in first week?) - I could reproduce it setting first day of week to SUNDAY (or default  `Locale` to `US`)

Comment: @gurioso It’s not a duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException on Calendar.getTime() when lenient is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214838/illegalargumentexception-on-calendar-gettime-when-lenient-is-false). The issue in that question was hitting a non-exisintg time in the spring transition to summer time (DST). That’s not the issue here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It’s not a duplicate of [Android Calendar illegalArgumentException when calendar.month set to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715369/android-calendar-illegalargumentexception-when-calendar-month-set-to-1). That question was about hitting a non-existing date of February 30. It’s not that something similar is happening here.

Comment: @OleV.V. didn't flag ('cause wasn't sure), just asked/proposed

Comment: Just fine, @gurioso, a suggestion is always welcome (I also didn’t reopen after the question was closed, at least not yet, unsure whether I ought to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Never use `Calendar`, now legacy, supplanted by *java.time* classes such as `ZonedDateTime`.

Use a purpose-built class, [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, to track standard [ISO 8601 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

### Custom formatter

Define a `DateTimeFormatter` object to match your non-standard input string.

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek
.parse(
    "202001" ,
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendValue( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
    .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 2)
    .toFormatter()
)
.toString()
```

> 2020-W01

### Standard formatter

Or manipulate your input string to comply with the [ISO 8601 standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), inserting a `-W` in the middle between the week-based-year and the week. The *java.time* classes and the *ThreeTen-Extra* classes all use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String input = "202001";
String inputModified = input.substring( 0 , 4 ) + "-W" + input.substring( 4 );
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.parse( inputModified ) ;
```

> yearWeek.toString(): 2020-W01

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Do not waste your time trying to understand `Calendar`. This terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Definition of week

You must specify your definition of a week. Do you mean week number 1 contains the first day of the year? Or week # 1contains a certain day of the week? Or week # 1 is the first calendar week to consist entirely of dates in the new year? Or perhaps an industry-specific definition of week? Some other definition?

One of the confusing things about `Calendar` is that its definition of a week shifts by `Locale`. This one of many reasons to avoid that legacy class.

## Week-based year

Depending on your definition of week, the year of a week may not be the calendar year of some dates on that week. A week-based year may overlap with calendar years.

## Standard weeks and week-based year

For example, the [standard ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) defines a week as:

- Starting on Monday, and
- Week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the calendar year.

So there are 52 or 53 whole weeks in every week-based year. Of course, that means some dates from the previous and/or following calendar years may appear in the first/last weeks of our week-based year.

## `org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`

One problem is that you are trying to represent a year-week with a class that represents a moment, a date with time of day in the context of a time zone.

Instead, use a purpose-built class. You can find one in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html). This library extends the functionality of the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

With that class I would think that we could define a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your input using the formatting pattern `YYYYww` where the `YYYY` means a 4-digit year of week-based-year, and the `ww` means the two-digit week number. Like this:

```
// FAIL
String input = "202001" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "YYYYww" ) ;
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.parse( input , f ) ;
```

But using that formatter throws an [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) for reasons that escape me.

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '202001' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain YearWeek from TemporalAccessor: {WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=1, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2020},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
>
> …
>
> Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain YearWeek from TemporalAccessor: {WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=1, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2020},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
>
> …
>
> Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: WeekBasedYear

Alternatively, we can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to build up a `DateTimeFormatter` from parts. By perusing [the *OpenJDK* source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java) for Java 13 for [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE) I was able to cobble together this formatter that seems to work.

```
DateTimeFormatter f =  
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendValue( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
        .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 2)
        .toFormatter()
;
```

Using that:

```
String input = "202001" ; 
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.parse( input , f ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

Educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defining formats for representing date-time values textually.

To generate a string in standard format representing the value of our `YearWeek`, call `toString`.

```
String output = yearWeek.toString() ;
```

> 2020-W01

And parsing a standard string.

```
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.parse( "2020-W01" ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Basil. We are no where to reconfigure the entire project to open JDK. Cant switch from Calendar to sql.Time for now.

Comment: I ran it now 03:38 PM, 12/3/2019 - Tuesday, CST. The same code is throwing exception

Answer (score 2):

Basil Bourque has already provided a very good answer. Here’s one that doesn’t require an external dependency (provided you are using Java 8 or later).

### java.time

```
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.US);
    DateTimeFormatter yearWeekFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(wf.weekBasedYear(), 4)
            .appendValue(wf.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 2)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue())
            .toFormatter();

    String input = "202001";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, yearWeekFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output is:

> 2019-12-29

Assuming American weeks where Sunday is the first day of the week and week 1 is the week containing January 1, this is correct: week 1 of 2020 begins on Sunday, December 29, 2019. If you want weeks defined in some other way, just use a different `WeekFields` object.

I recommend that you don’t use the `Calendar` class. That class was always poorly designed and is now long outdated. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Any explanation?

With thanks to user85421 for how to reproduce. You are first creating a `Calendar` object (really an instance of `GregorianCalendar`) representing the current day, in your example Nov 22nd, 2020, a Sunday (apparently having set your computer clock nearly a year ahead). You are then setting its year to 2020 (no change) and its week number to 1. However, as we saw above, this would change the date to December 29, 2019, and thus create a conflict with the year that you set to 2020. Therefore `GregorianCalendar` decides that you are asking the impossible and throws the exception. The stack trace that I got was:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: YEAR: 2020 -> 2019
    at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2826)
    at java.base/java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3395)
    at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
    at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1755)
    at ovv.misc.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

In your second example you were running your program on Nov 27, 2020, a Friday. This time the date is changed to Friday, January 3, 2020, so still within year 2020, and therefore there is no conflict and hence no exception.

The explanation presumes that your default locale is one where week 1 of the year is defined as the week that contains January 1. I have ran your code in my own locale after setting my computer’s time to Nov 22, 2020, and my time zone to America/Chicago. No exception was seen (output included Sun Jan 05 13:54:27 CST 2020). My locale follows the international standard, ISO. Monday is the first day of the week, and week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days of the new year in it. So week 1 of 2020 is from Monday, December 30, 2019, through Sunday, January 5. I suppose that on a Monday or Tuesday I could reproduce your problem in this locale too, I haven’t tried.

### PS How to parse an integer

Just a tip, to parse a string into an `int`, just use `Integer.parseInt(yourString)`. No need to create a new `Integer` object.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was not able to reproduce it now even after setting the time in my local to Nov, 22nd. Good tip for the integer